Containerd error loading seccomp filter into kernel in kubernetes
Recently i get this error on one of the Kubernetes worker and on bitnami pods (redis, rabbitmq, mongodb) where the seccomp profile is defined.
(combined from similar events): Liveness probe errored: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to exec in container: failed to start exec "5d1b455a1607ba76e2f1776836f3cd8bd094fc9ffe66cbaac3d16d6a921d9489": OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: unable to init seccomp: error loading seccomp filter into kernel: error loading seccomp filter: errno 524: unknown

I tried:

Restart containers
Restart containerd and kubelet

and does't work.
I find a solution that i have to increase net.core.bpf_jit_limit but i am not sure what the effects are.
currently net.core.bpf_jit_limit is set to 528482304.
the OS is ubuntu and containerd version is 1.5.7, kubernetes version is 1.27.5, and kernel version on all nodes is 5.15.0-105-generic

When you say increasing net.core.bpf_jit_limit is a solution, do you mean you did that and it resolved your issue? I'm a bit surprised that you would have so many seccomp-bpf programs as to hit this limit. How many containers do you have on the host with a seccomp filter?

Hey,
I'm seeing the same thing on my GKE cluster, but didn't realize that it could be the secomp profile on the bitnami charts until I read this post [1] by essh and saw your question. My problem also goes away when I increase net.core.bpf_jit_limit, but once the limit is hit again any new pods that land on that node get stuck with the error you mentioned. Where are you running your k8s cluster?
[1] https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-eks-ami/issues/1219
